# Issues with React Native Navigation

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-native-navigation

I just faced an issue with react native navigation with 502 Bad Gateway.

Have a look at issue for below screenshot. Please help us if any idea on this.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I strongly recommand you to have a look to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Look at this,[react native issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24082)

jcenter is down.

keep updated with this.